# Posting multiple urls to Nextdns denylist issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to post multiple URLs to the denylist of my nextdns profile account howerver I'm getting errors, I followed the API but seems something is missing, I have bunch of URLs in blacklist_domains.txt file, I suspect something is wrong with the endpoint url? I will post my code, can you please spot something I couldn't catch?

PHP Code:

```
<?php
// Hardcoded Configurations
$nextdns_api_key = "API-KEY";
$nextdns_profile = "configID"; // Replace with your actual Config ID

// API Endpoint URL
$api_endpoint = "https://api.nextdns.io/profiles/$nextdns_profile/denylist";

// API Auth
$header = [
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "X-Api-Key: $nextdns_api_key"
];

// Initialize count_domains
$count_domains = 0;

// Open Domains File
$blacklistfile = fopen('blacklist_domains.txt', 'r');
if ($blacklistfile) {
    // Read the file line by line
    while (($domain = fgets($blacklistfile)) !== false) {
        $count_domains++;

        $response = denylist_blockdomain(trim($domain), $header, $api_endpoint);
        echo "Domain: $domain";
        echo "Response: $response" . PHP_EOL;

        // Check for errors in the response
        $json_response = json_decode($response, true);

        if (!empty($json_response) && isset($json_response['errors'])) {
            foreach ($json_response['errors'] as $error) {
                echo "Error Code: " . $error['code'] . PHP_EOL;
                echo "Error Detail: " . ($error['detail'] ?? '') . PHP_EOL;
                echo "Error Source: " . ($error['source']['parameter'] ?? '') . PHP_EOL;
            }
        }

        flush();
        sleep(2); // Adjust sleep time based on rate-limiting policies
    }

    // Close file
    fclose($blacklistfile);
} else {
    echo "Error opening the file." . PHP_EOL;
}

echo $count_domains . " Added to blacklist" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Done, exiting app" . PHP_EOL;

// Function definitions (replace with actual implementations)
function denylist_blockdomain($domain, $header, $api_endpoint) {
    // Implementation for blocking a domain in denylist
    // Example using curl:
    $data = json_encode(["denylist" => [["id" => $domain, "active" => true]]]);
    echo "Request Data: $data" . PHP_EOL;
    $ch = curl_init($api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
?>
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Domain: example1.net
Response: {"errors":[{"code":"notFound"}]}
Error Code: notFound
Error Detail: 
Error Source: 
Domain: example2.net
Response: {"errors":[{"code":"notFound"}]}
Error Code: notFound
Error Detail: 
Error Source: 
Domain: example3.com
Response: {"errors":[{"code":"notFound"}]}
Error Code: notFound
Error Detail: 
Error Source: 
3 Added to blacklist
Done, exiting app
```

Comment: You are making an individual request for each one, so your problem can rather hardly have anything to do with the fact that you are trying this for multiple domains one after the other. _"I suspect something is wrong with the endpoint url?"_ - where is the documentation you are basing this on, please link to it.

Comment: Here is the link to the documentation ```https://nextdns.github.io/api/``` look for Nested objects and arrays

Comment: The example for denylist in the JSON the provide on that page, is `"denylist": [{ "id": "badwebsite.com", "active": true }, { "id": "pornhub.com", "active": false }],`, whereas you appear to be sending only the domain, using the parameter name `name` ...?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve it honestly

Comment: By using the parameter name the API wants, instead of one you made up yourself ...?

Comment: Please check the edit I did, I still get the error:
```Request Data: {"denylist":[{"id":"yahoo.com","active":true}]}
Domain: yahoo.com
Response: {"errors":[{"code":"notFound"}]}
Error Code: notFound
Error Detail: 
Error Source: 
Request Data: {"denylist":[{"id":"pornhub.com","active":true}]}
Domain: pornhub.com
Response: {"errors":[{"code":"notFound"}]}
Error Code: notFound
Error Detail: 
Error Source: 
2 Added to blacklist
Done, exiting app
```

Comment: New Error:
```Domain: pornhub.com
Response: {"errors":[{"code":"required","source":{"pointer":""},"detail":"`` must have required property 'id'."},{"code":"extraneous","source":{"pointer":"/denylist"}}]}
Error Code: required
Error Detail: `` must have required property 'id'.
Error Source: 
Error Code: extraneous
Error Detail: 
Error Source: 
2 Added to blacklist
Done, exiting app
```

Comment: `{"code":"extraneous","source":{"pointer":"/denylist"}}` - you are targeting the `.../denylist` endpoint with your URL already, so the JSON you send must not contain `denylist` again.